# Get the ID in row that has radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, onclick, radio-button

I have this function which creates a table in a modal popup and the table gets populated from data in an array passed in from an ajax call. Now on the click of a button in the modal popup I need to get the value of item.TimedPathwayID that has its radio button checked and add it to a hidden field.

```
function PopulateTimedPathwaysTable(tblData) {
var tbody = $('#tblTimedPathways tbody');
$.map(tblData.d, function (item) {
    tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    tr.append('<td class="pathwayID">' + item.TimedPathwayID + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.TimedPathwayName + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td><input type="radio" class="radioSelection" name="timedPathwaySelection"" />');
    tbody.append(tr);
});
$('input[name=timedPathwaySelection]:first').attr('checked', true);}
}
```

I've been fiddling with this kind of thing but with no joy and the radio button in the first row is checked by default so this can't really be tied to a click event if a user just accepts the default without clicking. So how can I do it please?

```
$('body').on('click', '.radioSelection', function () {
    var $tbl = $('#tblTimedPathways tbody');
    var $dataRow = $tbl.closest('tr');
    var id = $dataRow.find('td').eq(0).html(); 
});
```

Comment: @freedomn-m ok thanks but what if there isn't a click event and just the id from the row with its default button checked is required?

Comment: Without a click event (so no `this`) you can get the current radio with `$("[name=timedPathwaySelection]:checked")` example: https://jsfiddle.net/xnr0om9k/

Comment: @freedomn-m not sure that's working?

Comment: Well you need to combine the radio selector with .closest(tr) and .find(.pathwayID).text().   You also need to ensure you call it at the right time, ie after your tbody.append.

Comment: Note that you should only use `$.map` when you want to return an array - otherwise you should use `.each`.  No real reason, just that's what `$.each`/`$.map` is for.

Comment: unbelievably this works but its a big hack - is there a more elegant way to write it? $("[name=timedPathwaySelection]:checked").closest('td').prev().prev().text()

Comment: It's hardly a hack.  Using `.prev().prev()` is dangerous though as it will break if you move your td's - what was wrong with `.cloest("tr").find(".pathwayID").text()`?

Comment: You could give your radio's a class (which you have), so it would be `$(".radioSelection:checked").closest("tr")`, depending on which part you consider a "big hack" (the [name=] selector or the .prev())

Comment: thanks for your help guys - have a nice weekend

Answer (score 0):

- .closest goes up the html tree, so tbody.closest(tr) is unlikely to be what you want.
- you need to then go back down to the cell that contains the data you want.

```
 let $this = $(this);  //this is the radio button
 let id = $this.closest("tr").find("td.pathwayID").text();
```

I would also echo that I would generally add the `id` as an attribute to the row to remove the necessity of the find later.

```js
//sample data
let data = {
  d: [{
      TimedPathwayID: 1,
      TimedPathwayName: "test"
    },
    {
      TimedPathwayID: 2,
      TimedPathwayName: "test"
    },
    {
      TimedPathwayID: 3,
      TimedPathwayName: "test"
    }
  ]
};

function PopulateTimedPathwaysTable(tblData) {
  var tbody = $('#tblTimedPathways tbody');
  $.map(tblData.d, function(item) {
    tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    tr.append('<td class="pathwayID">' + item.TimedPathwayID + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + item.TimedPathwayName + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td><input type="radio" class="radioSelection" name="timedPathwaySelection"" />');
    tbody.append(tr);
  });
  $('input[name=timedPathwaySelection]:first').attr('checked', true);
}
//populate it
PopulateTimedPathwaysTable(data);

$('body').on('click', '.radioSelection', function () {
    let $this = $(this);  //this is the radio button
    //console.log($this);
    let id = $this.closest("tr").find("td.pathwayID").text();
    console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblTimedPathways">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Apologies, adding comments isn't ideal.  I tend to do so when I don't have time for a full answer, but that's just a bad excuse.

Comment: no blame, and now I feel bad answering essentially the exact same as you.  I also tend to just quickly get an answer down and then work to elaborate.  this isn't ideal either.

Comment: If both of y'all could find the duplicate before commenting or answering, we'd all be better off :-P.

Comment: @Steve0 same question was levelled at freedomn-m but what if there isn't a radio button click event, but there is a click in the modal popup where the table lives?

Comment: @HereticMonkey another reason for not giving a full answer - there's *always* a duplicate :)